# Add custom Model Binders for derived objects and their base

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

My class diagram:

BaseContentClass

- Page inherits BaseContentClass
- Tab inherits BaseContentClass
- ...

If I do this

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(BaseContentObject), new BaseContentObjectCommonPropertiesBinder());
```

then when in controller action parameter of type Tab appears, custom model binder is not fired.

It gets fired if I do this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Tab), new BaseContentObjectCommonPropertiesBinder());
```

But I don't want to go writing "n" number of Add statements in my global.asax.cs to associate all the derived classes with my custom model binder, do I? I don't know if I have any other option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this instead.  I haven't tested it, but I'm fairly certain it will work.

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(BaseContentObjectCommonPropertiesBinder))]
public class BaseContentObject {}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [ModelBinders.Binders property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinders.binders(VS.100).aspx) is of type [ModelBinderDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelbinderdictionary(v=VS.100).aspx) which uses the type as a key.  As a result it will ignore you registering the model binder for the base class.  Reading this [article from Los Techies](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/03/17/a-better-model-binder.aspx) I think you might be able to get around this by defining a binder attribute upon the type, see the order precedence in the article.